# Method paginate does not exist Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I get the following error when I try to paginate in Laravel 5.2.

> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 81: Method paginate does
>   not exist.

And code:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Pagination\Paginator;
...
       $count = 0;
        $gdprecords = Gdprecord::all();
        foreach($gdprecords as $gdprecord) {
            $count++;
            $Pa = $gdprecord->adultpopulation;
            $Pc = $gdprecord->childpopulation;
            $P = $Pa + $Pc;  // total population
            $T = ($gdprecord->gdpcapita * $P) * $gdpratio;  // basic income for country 
            if($bi_ratio == 0) { 
                $gdprecord->bi_adult = round($T / $Pa, 2);
            } else {
                $gdprecord->bi_adult = round($T / ($Pa + ($Pc / $bi_ratio)), 2);
            }
            $gdprecord->bi_adult_monthly = round($gdprecord->bi_adult / 12, 2);
            $gdprecord->bi_adult_daily = round($gdprecord->bi_adult / 365, 2);
            if($bi_ratio == 0) {
                $gdprecord->bi_child = 0;
            } else {
                $gdprecord->bi_child = round($gdprecord->bi_adult / $bi_ratio, 2);
            }
            $gdprecord->bi_child_monthly = round($gdprecord->bi_child / 12, 2);
            $gdprecord->bi_child_daily = round($gdprecord->bi_child / 365, 2);                    
        }
        $sorted_gdprecords = $gdprecords->sortByDesc('bi_adult')->paginate(25);
```

I don't want to paginate until after the array has been sorted.  How do I make this work?

Thanks, Philip

Comment: Can you please add your eloquent query?

Comment: @wiesson, it's in the post, `$gdprecords = Gdprecord::all();`

Comment: The boring answer is that you need to figure out how to add your sorting criteria into the query, since the paginate function doesn't work on collections. It's a best practice anyway, but I realise it can be quite hard - perhaps you could add that info into some fields on the table as data is added, and sort based on that? Otherwise it looks like you'll have to write your own pagination, and since it's collection-based, it likely won't be very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found, borrowing code from someone else:

```
    public function paginate($items,$perPage)
    {
        $pageStart = \Request::get('page', 1);
        // Start displaying items from this number;
        $offSet = ($pageStart * $perPage) - $perPage; 

        // Get only the items you need using array_slice
        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($items, $offSet, $perPage, true);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($items), $perPage,Paginator::resolveCurrentPage(), array('path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()));
    }
```

and add this code:

```
  $gdprecords2 = $gdprecords->sortByDesc('bi_adult')->all();
  $perPage = 25;
  $sorted_gdprecords = self::paginate($gdprecords2, $perPage);
```

Thanks for your help. -Philip